# Why does reassigning a linked list in python not break the link to another linked list?

Tags: python, class

I am pretty new to python and have been going through some hackerrank challenges.

The problem I'm having trouble understanding with involves merging 2 sorted linked lists:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists/problem

What I don't understand is how in this solution, when we set curr = head, then set curr.next = curr1, then set curr = curr.next, "head" only receives the .next additions to the list. The link between curr and head is not broken even though we set curr = curr.next.

I think I am just failing to understand something fundamental about python, but I'm unsure how to search for it. Thanks.

```
def mergeLists(head1, head2):
    if head1 is None:
        return head2
    if head2 is None:
        return head1

    if head1.data <= head2.data:
        head = head1
        curr1 = head1.next
        curr2 = head2
    else:
        head = head2
        curr1 = head1
        curr2 = head2.next

    curr = head
        
    while True:
        if curr1 is None:
            curr.next = curr2
            break
        elif curr2 is None:
            curr.next = curr1
            break

        if curr1.data <= curr2.data:
            curr.next = curr1
            curr1 = curr1.next
        else:
            curr.next = curr2
            curr2 = curr2.next
        
        curr = curr.next

    return head
```

Comment: For things like this I like to draw it on a piece of paper and see what the relationships between objects look like. It usually makes things a lot clearer.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "the link between curr and head is not broken".

Comment: Here is my thought process:
When I assign curr = head, they are linked.

When I set curr.next = curr1, head.next is also set to curr1, this makes sense to me.

When I set curr = curr.next, in my mind this is reassigning curr, so the link to head should be broken. But as you continue through the loop and continue to set curr.next = curr1, head.next continues to be updated. Does that make sense?

Comment: It doesn't keep updating. put print(head.next) in the loop and it will always return the same object. curr will go from pointing to head to head.next to head.next.next and so on as the list is built.

Comment: This actually helped me understand. Setting curr=curr.next doesn't break the link to head because curr.next is also linked to head. I don't know why this was so hard for me to wrap my brain around. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with objects, python allows us to interact with the object using references.  So in this case, neither head, nor curr, or curr1 are actually Nodes in the linked list, as Nodes are of data type object.  head, curr, and curr1 are all references to objects, which are basically just labels.

In the physical world, you make a label "A", and put it on a box. If you peel label "A" off the box at a later date, and put it on a new box, you haven't actually changed the boxes. You have only changed what you call the boxes.  Additionally, you can put as many labels on a box as you want.  The same goes for python references to objects.

- head starts as a label for the first node object in the linked list.
- curr = head means "create a new label called curr, and put it on the same object as the existing label called head"
- curr.next = curr1 means "modify the object referenced by curr at this time, and update its "next" attribute to point to the same object curr1 currently points to".  We know this action modifies the node object (not the reference) because ".next" portion accesses an attribute of the object, which is currently known as curr... but is also known as head from earlier.
- curr = curr.next means "remove the reference called curr from the object it is currently on, and put it on the object that curr1 is currently pointing to".
- changing the label "curr" to point to a different object does not change the object that head has been pointing to all along (since we never removed it from its original object, nor have we reassigned it to a new object).
- head still points to the original object, but we modified the "next" attribute of the object previously to point to the same object curr1 points to.

the end result is head points to a node, which has a next attribute that points to another node, which currently has two labels: curr and curr1.

This is why most linked list problems create a second variable called curr, and have head = curr.  The curr label lets us use the same name to refer to any number of nodes as we transverse the linked list, while head acts like a bookmark at the top of the list that we can always refer back to if we need to get back to the top of the list for some reason.

below is some simple code that can be experimented with to better understand references vs object (Node objects in this case).

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


# both curr and head point at the actual object, which is a specific instance of class Node
curr = head = Node(0)
for i in range(1, 4):
     # create a new Node object, and make that Node object the next node in the linked list.
    curr.next = Node(i)

# move the REFERENCE we called curr, to the next Node object.
    curr = curr.next

# head still points to the node object with value 0
print(head.val)

# curr points to the node object with value 3, since the for loop reassigned this reference
# to each node that was created in the loop,  with the last node having a value of 3.
print(curr.val)
```